# Function getMapCenter in MapFragment / get MapView from MapFragment

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I have a MapFragment in my Android app and now I would like to know the min and max lat/long that is shown on the map actual.

I found this solution:

> If you want to find out the longitude latitude of the corners of the MapView you could use:

```
Point mapCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
int latitudeSpan = mapView.getLatitudeSpan() / 2;
int longitudeSpan = mapView.getLongitudeSpan() / 2;
int topLeftLat = mapCenter.getLatitudeE6() + (latitudeSpan);
int topLeftLon = mapCenter.getLongitudeE6() - (longitudeSpan);
int bottomLeftLat = mapCenter.getLatitudeE6() - (latitudeSpan);
int bottomLeftLon = mapCenter.getLongitudeE6() + (longitudeSpan);
```

My problem now is that I dont have a MapView,
I only have a GoogleMap (com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap) and a MapFragment (com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment) .

I need the min/max coordinates to do a DB query for selecting POI-DB-Entrys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from your `GoogleMap` using [`getVisibleRegion`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection#getVisibleRegion%28%29) from `Projection`.

Assuming you named your `GoogleMap` as `map`, you do

```
VisibleRegion bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```

`VisibleRegion` is not necessarily a rectangle, but gives you the bounds, see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this in the Evening. Looks like this is what I searched.

Answer (score 0):

To add to iagreen's answer, you are probably interested in the LatLngBounds on the visible region call.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = this.mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

From that, you can get the min/max latitude/longitude (northeast / southwest corners).

Not sure what you're trying to do with this, but if you are looking to check if a Marker is "on screen", then you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713335/1103584)