# Reducing Android Map shape overlapping draws

Tags: android, performance, google-maps-android-api-2

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, but the questions I find don't have an answer (I hope to simplify those questions).

Given two circles on a GoogleMap, how do I tell if they overlap and "smash" them into one image?

I have a lot of data points (~14K) and that many circles are not rendering well. Can they also be drawn just once, instead of 14k draw calls?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Google Maps API Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering). That should handle clustering your items for you.

And there is a [SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495171/cluster-markers-in-google-maps-android-v2) addressing the same issue and solutions as well.

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. I need to place markers to see where I've been. Kind of like polyline, but without order.

Comment: What is the difference between what you need and Google Maps Clustering Utility ? Don't you want to cluster the markers if they are close enough to each other ?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to draw data points (semitransparent circles) to fill in a map. Realistically, I would like to turn my data into one giant polygon, but I don't know how to make 100 or more overlapping circles into one shape. Clusters would just make them a grouped circle.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you just want to be able to draw circles on the map. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812104/1080954) in this SOF Q/A it shows how you can Add Bitmaps into Map. This way you can also draw Circles inside a Canvas. Take a look.

Comment: I'll have to look into that later.