# Android mapview 2.0 slowdown on return from specific activity

Tags: android, google-maps

This is a very difficult one to explain. Basically we have a tabbed layout with a mapview on one of the tabs. The mapview behaves normally except for one thing.

I have an activity that allows a location to be stored by the following means:

**1- Long press on the map and add a location.**

**2- Use a searchbar to find a location and then add location.**

**3- Activity to do a postcode lookup and return location.**

Strange thing is to save the location they all call the "name location and save" activity. However number 1 on return the map is super slow and clunky.
2 and 3 however have not got this issue.

Has anyone any loose ideas about what could be causing this? I thought it could be a memory leak or something (like creating the mapview twice) but this does not -seem- to be the issue.

Any ideas or anyone with a similar problem and how they solved it would be very helpful.

Comment: If you are in debug mode with a emulator or device, the application is much more slow than release aplication. Especially if you are using google maps v2. In your tab with map, you should use getMapAsync to load map, so will not stop the main thread

Comment: For the `google map` slow in the android, you may check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713066/google-maps-android-api-v2-very-slow-when-adding-lots-of-markers) to get some ideas.